# Items inside Groups in ICollectionView are not sorted

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, icollectionview

I have an `ObservableCollection<string>`:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>
{
    "AA",
    "BB",
    "CC",
    "C",
    "A",
    "C",
    "BBB",
    "AAA",
    "CCC"
};
```

A `ListBox` in the Window binds to this Collection. In the Window Loaded event, I am assigning sorting and grouping logic to the underlying ICollectionView of the `Collection`.

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ICollectionView defaultView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Collection);
    defaultView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(null, new TestGroupConverter()));

    defaultView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    defaultView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("", ListSortDirection.Descending));
}
```

`TestGroupConverter` returns the length of the string in its convert method.

So here's the result:

[image]

I expected the groups to be sorted in ascending order and items within it to be sorted by descending order. But it appears that the `SortDescription` for items within the group is not used — It's not sorted in Descending order.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Get the first letter of string: `collection.OrderBy(x>x.Substring(0,1))`

Comment: @MaciejLos, I didn't understand. SortDescription uses the Default Comparer for strings.

Comment: @EmperorAiman did you try changing first `SortDescription` to `new SortDescription("Length", ListSortDirection.Ascending)` so primary sort is by items length?

Comment: @dkozl, ah. Yes. That fixed the problem. I thought the first sortdescription uses the `CollectionViewGroups.Name` for it's sorting. My bad.

So sorting is independent of grouping. Thanks. You can make this into an answer if you want. I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All sort descriptions apply to items even when you use grouping and you have two sort descriptions with the same property. Unfortunately you cannot sort by converted value but you can change first `SortDescription` to sort by `Length` property

```
defaultView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Length", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
defaultView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```